# Почему программа работает только пока c не превысит (a+b)^3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа-фибоначчи

**Задача**: Напишите программу, которая из двух заданных натуральных чисел `a` и `b` создаст список, содержащий элементы , являющиеся элементами последовательности Фибоначчи, по алгоритму:

```
c = a + b 
a = b
b = c
```

пока `c` не превысит `(a+b)^3`, затем вернет сумму всех элементов созданного списка.
Например:
Для `a=2`, `b=4` он вернет список символов `[6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, 178]` и сумму `456`.

Мой код:

```
a, b = 2, 4
L = []
c = 0
while c != (a + b) ** 3:
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        L.append(c)
print(L)
print(sum(L))
```

Мне нужно, чтобы он выдавал `[6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, 178]` и сумму `456`, но он даже не компилируется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как так не компилируется? Он прекрасно компилируется и отлично работает. Единственное в чём его можно упрекнуть - он очень старается и делает больше чем вы, как вам кажется, попросили.

Comment: Ошибка тут: `while c != (a + b) ** 3:`. Их две: одна простая, вторая похитрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примеру, вам нужно запомнить начальные значения `a,b` и сравнивать `с` с кубом их суммы.

И "пока не превысит" не означает, что нужно ловить строгое равенство.

```
t = (a + b) ** 3
c = a + b
while c <= t:
    L.append(c)
    a = b
    b = c
    c = a + b
```